# Flutter freezed convert List to json

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-freezed

this is my two `freezed` class which i want to make a simple `json` from `ContactsData`

```dart
@freezed
class ContactsData with _$ContactsData {
  const factory ContactsData({
    String? displayName,
    String? givenName,
    String? familyName,
    String? company,
    String? jobTitle,
    List<ContactPhone>? phones,
  }) = _ContactsData;

  factory ContactsData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ContactsDataFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class ContactPhone with _$ContactPhone {
  const factory ContactPhone({
    String? label,
    String? value,
  }) = _ContactPhone;

  factory ContactPhone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ContactPhoneFromJson(json);
}
```

i added some data into `allContacts` by this code:

```dart
late List<ContactsData> allContacts=[];

contacts?.forEach((c) {
  List<ContactPhone> phones=[];
  c.phones!.forEach((f) =>phones.add(ContactPhone(label: f.label,value: f.value)));
  allContacts.add(
    ContactsData(
      displayName:c.displayName,
      givenName: c.givenName,
      familyName: c.familyName,
      company: c.company,
      jobTitle: c.jobTitle,
      phones: phones,
    )
  );
});
```

now how can i convert allContacts to `json` like with this code:

```
allContacts.toJson();
```

`build.yaml`:

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          explicit_to_json: true
```

Comment: Could you specify a question for this post, pls?

Comment: @powerman23rus converting `allContacts` list to a `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allContacts is just a regular List.

Either:

1. make it an object (possibly even a freezed object) similar to ContactsData and call it something like ContactsCollection or something better... and add toJson method to it.

Or

2. Do something like `jsonEncode(allContacts.map((c) => c.toJson()).toList())`